# how to save data localy without using database

Tags: java, class, object

suppose that I have an `Employee` Class and there is another Class `Company` that has more than one `Employee` so I want to save the `Employee` objects locally, that means every time I run my application I can retrieve these objects.

Comment: check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) for saving and retrieving objects as streams

Comment: you can use files but than you wil have to implement CRUD operations yourself and it's kinda mess... use database!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html You can also consider converting your object to XML or JSON.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use Microsoft Excel to save the attributes of this object and retrieve them later, there is an api for excel http://poi.apache.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some kind of embedded solution. There are a number of options available such as [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/).

For a comprehensive list check out [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database).

Although these solutions are technically databases the don't run on their own server, they run inside your current Java process.

To get started with *H2* the following steps are required:

- Add the h2*.jar to the classpath (H2 does not have any dependencies)
- Use the JDBC driver class: org.h2.Driver
- The database URL jdbc:h2:~/test opens the database test in your user home directory
- A new database is automatically created

After that, you can simply use JDBC against the new database everything is stored on disk.

I would **not** recommend using Java-serialization of Java objects to a file (`Serializable`). This is not a maintanable solution and whenever your code changes (for the classes that were serialized) you have to work out some plan on how to migrate your data.

Another solution is to dump your object graph as JSON in a file. There are multiple libraries that can help you with serialization and deserialization from Java to JSON and vice versa. One example is the excellent [Jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) that easily and without fuzz converts objects to and from JSON.